# phpMyAdmin MySQL TimeStamp Shows Trailing Zeroes

Tags: php, mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

Does anyone know why in phpMyAdmin/MySQL displaying Time Stamps changed from:

```
2012-10-20 08:43:28
```

to

```
2012-10-20 08:43:28.000000
```

with trailing zeroes. This seems to have started with the release of phpMyAdmin Version 4. Would like the Time Stamp to show as:

```
2012-10-20 08:43:28
```

The attributes of the field are Name: date, Type: timestamp, Default: Current_Timestamp.

Comment: Did the version of MySQL change? The reason I ask is because "[MySQL 5.6.4](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/fractional-seconds.html) and up expands fractional seconds support for TIME, DATETIME, and TIMESTAMP values, with up to microseconds (6 digits) precision."

Comment: No, the version of MySQL did not change. Just as as test I went back and opened the database in phpMyAdmin 3.53 and the time stamp is displaying correctly 2012-10-20 08:43:28 without the trailing zeroes. I am currently running phpMyAdmin 4.1.6. I guess if it bothers me that much I could just go back and use ver3.5.3 or any version prior to 4 but I am just curious why the trailing zeroes are there in the newer version.

Comment: But what version of MySQL is it? If you're already using 5.6+, it could be that the older phpMyAdmin wasn't displaying it properly (which, according to the [4.1 release notes](http://sourceforge.net/p/phpmyadmin/news/2013/12/phpmyadmin-410-is-released/), was the case). If you want that display, you could take a look at [this](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format) when you run your select statements.

Comment: It's just a display issue and has nothing to do with the data actually in the database, so I am not sure why you care.

Comment: Nevermind. I just downloaded the latest version of phpMyAdmin 4.1.7 and the trailing zeroes are no longer appearing. Must have been a bug in v4 they finally fixed. Thank you for your replies.

Comment: Ah, ok. I'm glad you were able to figure it out!

Comment: Its funny, my PDO query results include this float number, but the same query does not on phpmyadmin side!? Anyone?

Answer (score 1):

phpMyAdmin began displaying the fractional part of timestamps as of [4.1.0](http://sourceforge.net/p/phpmyadmin/news/2013/12/phpmyadmin-410-is-released/). If you'd like to display your timestamps without the fractional part, you can adapt this query:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(`date`, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s') FROM your_table;
```

The result would look like this:

```
MariaDB [my_database]> SELECT DATE_FORMAT(`date`, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s') `date` 
    FROM your_table LIMIT 1;
+---------------------+
| date                |
+---------------------+
| 2014-01-22 17:54:11 |
+---------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [my_database]>
```

Comment: You're right, but it's easier than that. As you point out, it's a feature (not a bug as the OP suggested) for phpMyAdmin to display fractional timestamps, but the initial implementation was overzealous with the display, so it was fixed in a more recent version.