# My date with datetime format is inserted in my table with more zeros that was supposed

Tags: php, mysql, sql, datetime

Im have a news table in my database with field "date", that is a datetime.

And Im inserting a date into database, my date have this format "Sunday, 1 June, 2014", and I need to convert it to datetime before my insert.

So I convert my date to datetime:

```
$english = array(); //have words in english
$spanish = array(); //have words in spanish                 
$result_date = str_ireplace ($english , $spanish, $f['date']);
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('l, j F, Y', $result_date);
$date = $data->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

And then I do my insert:

```
$insert = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO news (title,date) VALUES (:title,:date)");  
$insert->bindValue(':title', $f['title']);
$insert->bindValue(':date', $date);
$insert->execute();
```

The problem is, Im getting date in database like this: 2014-05-28 02:57:46.000000

And I dont understand, why this last 6 zeros appears.

Do you know why they are appear? And how I can remove it??

Comment: This looks similar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21688680/phpmyadmin-mysql-timestamp-shows-trailing-zeroes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `datetime` and `timestamp` columns support precision up to the microsecond, as described in the [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/datetime.html):

> A DATETIME or TIMESTAMP value can include a trailing fractional
>   seconds part in up to microseconds (6 digits) precision. In
>   particular, any fractional part in a value inserted into a DATETIME or
>   TIMESTAMP column is stored rather than discarded. With the fractional
>   part included, the format for these values is 'YYYY-MM-DD
>   HH:MM:SS[.fraction]', the range for DATETIME values is '1000-01-01
>   00:00:00.000000' to '9999-12-31 23:59:59.999999', and the range for
>   TIMESTAMP values is '1970-01-01 00:00:01.000000' to '2038-01-19
>   03:14:07.999999'. The fractional part should always be separated from
>   the rest of the time by a decimal point; no other fractional seconds
>   delimiter is recognized. For information about fractional seconds
>   support in MySQL, see Section 11.3.6, “Fractional Seconds in Time
>   Values”.

Your value is being stored correctly,  If you want to retrieve it in a particular way (such as with no fractional seconds), then use `date_format()` to pull the data out as a formatted string.  In your case, you seem to want the format `'%y-%m-%d %h:%i:%s'`.

Comment: It is funny, that when i get for example , updatedon date, it returns correct, but when i use the convert_tz(updatedon,'UTC','+1:00') it does return with that extra float. But only when using the pdo script, since on the phpmyadmin query it returns normal.

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead.

```
INSERT INTO news VALUES (:title, STR_TO_DATE(:date, '%Y-%m-%d %h:%i:%s'))
```